# Stability of a torus in a dynamic system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

I have a nonlinear dynamic system with $n$ degrees of freedom:

$\dot{x} = f(x,t)$

In simulations a stable attractor can be found. I assume it is a torus because:

1. In the frequency spectrum it has two significant frequencies.
2. The Poincaré map shows an area of intersections.
3. I could create a hypersphere and for a long simulation time the solutions would constantly stay in that sphere.

By now I only know how to determine the stability of limit cycles using Poincaré maps by calculating the Jacobi and monodromy matrix resulting in Lyapunov exponents. This does not seem to be valid for tori!

Do you know other possibilities to determine the stability of a torus by Lyapunov by other means? Pleas note that the dynamic system is so non-linear it can only be solved numerically.

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite exactly sure what exactly you want to show, but the following may help:

- The signs of the first Lyapunov exponents of a (stable) quasiperiodic dynamics (torus) should be 00−, 000−, etc. In your case, I would expect 00−. A periodic dynamics would have 0−; a chaotic one would have +0− (or ++0−, +00−, or similar).
- The autocorrelation function of a quasiperiodic dynamics does not decay. (For a chaotic dynamics, it does.)
- If you do not see any changes in the characteristics of a dynamics over a long simulation, this is a good indicator that it is stable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I found a method leading to the Lyapunov exponents (this was something i was not able to get previously). The used method by Parker and Chua (Practical Numerical Algorithms for Chaotic systems) results in the Lyapunov exponents by using the Gram-Schmidt Orthonormalization technique. 
One new Problem is that Parker and Chua say at least one Lyapunov exponent calculated by the method should be zero for a limited set that is not a Equilibrium point. In my example all Lyapunov exponents are negative meaning the system is Stable but missing the one ore two Zeros.

Comment: The question is, does a torus always have to have two Lyapunov exponents that are Zero and if so where could be a mistake on my part?

Comment: @Dnamix: Yes, you really should have two zeros for a torus. There are all sorts of mistakes you could have made here, but a lot boils down to applying a proper statistics to your local Lyapunov exponents and being aware that numerical estimates will never be exactly zero. First of all, I would ensure that you do not have a fixed-point dynamics (just let the system evolve for a long time). If that is the case, any analysis that does not yield a zero Lyapunov exponent must have a flaw.

Comment: I just evolved the system for a long time (50 sec for a system with a Characteristic frequency of >250 Hz) and the result is still a torus. But with the method described by Parker and Chua the Lyapunov exponents are converting to 4 Values (the system is of 4 DGL 1. Order) that are all lower than -50.
I had to do two things differently than the Methode i am Following. 
1. The Pertubation added to the initial Value is much lower than 1 (which is taken by Parker and Chua) because else one of the initial values wouldn´t be in the basine of attraktion
2. I dont use the Variational Equation

Comment: Instead of the Variational Equation i am just evolving the 4 pertubations as well as the initial condition. Buy this i still get the Solution of the Variational Equation by subtracting the solution of the Initial condition from the 4 solution given by the pertubation

Comment: I just realized something that couled be a big mistake? If i change the length of the time averaged over, the value of the Lyapunov exponents change, despite the sum of the Pertubation is devided by the time.

Comment: @Dnamix: I think the only way I can help you is with seeing your code or knowing your differential equations or more detailed results. Either way, this goes far beyond the scope of this question. But yes, the Lyapunov exponent depending on the measurement time is a strong indication of something going wrong.

Comment: The algorithm to calculate all Lyapunov exponents still does not work, but i used an algorithm to calculate the highest Lyapunov exponent (from http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/chaos/lyapexp.htm) the results look very good! For a system with a stable limited cycle (one Period) the highest Lyapunov exponent is near 0 as expected.
But the results, i thought about to be a stable torus, the highest Lyapunov exponent is positive. Does this mean the limited set is Chaotic? How can someone differentiate between a torus and a Chaotic limited set? Does this still mean that this limited set is stable?

Comment: And do you know maybe a simple algorythm (which is well explainedas the one by sprott) to calculate all lyapunov exponents?

Comment: *How can someone differentiate between a torus and a Chaotic limited set? Does this still mean that this limited set is stable?* – Well, see the other points of my answer. — *And do you know maybe a simple algorythm (which is well explainedas the one by sprott) to calculate all lyapunov exponents?* – Simple algorithms do not necessarily make things better, but I published [a software](https://github.com/neurophysik/jitcode) that automatises most of the process and thus should avoid mistakes.

Comment: Are there other ways to distinguish between chaos and tori besides the Lyapunov exponents? 

And if it is chaos, is it stable only if the sum of all Lyapunov exponents are smaller than zero?

Comment: *Are there other ways to distinguish between chaos and tori besides the Lyapunov exponents?* – Yes, it’s in my answer. — *And if it is chaos, is it stable only if the sum of all Lyapunov exponents are smaller than zero* – Chaos is recurrent and thus at least approximately stable per definition (you may have something called *long chaotic transients* though). You can get the sum of Lyapunov exponents (for a bounded dynamics) being smaller than zero from the [Kaplan–Yorke conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Yorke_conjecture) and probably more easily otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I have looked at the Lyapunov exponents and also the autocorrelation and it seems to be a chaotic behavior! A Lyapunov exponent is positive and the acf shows a declining behavior.
I would never have thought that even the simplest systems (2 degrees of freedom) could have such a chaotic behaviour. I had always considered them to be Quasi Periodic Solutions (Tori), because the fft also shows two significant frequencies (which speaks for a torus).
But with these two tools it should be easier for me to understand the solutions of dynamic systems. Thank you!

Comment: @Dnamix: With two degrees of freedom, i.e., two dynamic variables, you should neither see chaotic nor quasiperiodic behaviour. (That is unless you are looking at a DDE or similar.)

Comment: Well i do not know what DDE means but i am looking at a 2. order nonlinear 2 dof system.

Comment: @Dnamix: *DDE* means *delay differential equation.* If you are second order, this effectively doubles your degrees of freedom, so you can have chaos and tori. A classical example for this is the double pendulum.